# Angular: External scripts stops working after redirection with router-outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, adminlte, router-outlet

I am using Angular 6 with the AdminLTE template.
I have defined the styles and scripts in the angular.json file.

The styles work, but somehow the scripts do no longer work after a page-redirection using the router-outlet of angular.

As I cannot get this working on StackBlitz, I have uploaded a stripped down example to GitHub. After checking out use npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular to get it work.

https://github.com/cactusjack66/ScriptRouteTest.git

After the first page is loaded, the minimize button in the top right corner of the box works, but after redirecting to page2 it stops working...

Comment: Please share the path you have set in package.json

Comment: Which path do you mean? There is no path set in there, you can just checkout the project and the package.json is right there.

Comment: Ho @CactusJack I have create a Stackblitz demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-external-scripts-stops-working-after-redirection-with-r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

This is working fine

Comment: Hm, somehow for me this does not work at all. The minimize button at the right top corner should minimize the box, which it does not. In my example this works until redirection to page2.